# Django-haystack with rest-framework serializer gives result None

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I'm trying to use `django-haystack` to include an `elasticsearch` based search in my application. I'm using `django-rest-framework` to build the API. Following is my index:

```
class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Artist
```

This is my view:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if q is '':
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    all_results = SearchQuerySet().models(Artist).filter(content=Clean(q))
    serializer = ArtistSerializer(all_results, many=True)
    print serializer.data
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And my serializer:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = (
            'name',
            'type',
            'gender',
            'begin_life',
            'end_life',
        )
```

However, when I hit the endpoint, the `print` statement prints something like this:

```
[{'name': None, 'type': None, 'gender': None, 'begin_life': None, 'end_life': None}, {'name': None, 'type': None, 'gender': None, 'begin_life': None, 'end_life': None}, {'name': None, 'type': None, 'gender': None, 'begin_life': None, 'end_life': None}, {'name': None, 'type': None, 'gender': None, 'begin_life': None, 'end_life': None}, {'name': None, 'type': None, 'gender': None, 'begin_life': None, 'end_life': None}]
```

Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better way to serialize the data. I am now using this:

```
from django.core import serializers

-- snippet --

def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if q is '':
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    all_results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=Clean(q))
    serializer = serializers.serialize("json", [q.object for q in all_results])
    print serializer
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now, I am able to search in multiple models without worrying about serializing the data :)

The result data is like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "name": "Megadeth",
        "end_life": "",
        "gid": "a9044915-8be3-4c7e-b11f-9e2d2ea0a91e",
        "gender": "",
        "type": "2",
        "begin_life": "1983-6-"
    },
    "model": "InQusic.artist",
    "pk": 975773
}
```

so, now I can possibly differentiate results on my client.